# Struggling to get my Firestore rules correct - either users can see all users data or none. What am I getting wrong?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For reference here is the data being accessed in Firestore:

[image]

I feel like the issue lies somewhere in the EventID's in the second column, but here are my current rules:

```
    rules_version = '2';     ​

service cloud.firestore {    
  match /databases/{database}/documents {   
  

    match /Events/{docId} {     
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

    }

  }

}
```

This one works, but obviously, as long as the user is authorized, they can see everyone's data.

This is what I tried, which I thought should work:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /Events/{docId} { 
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Which, if I have it right, should ONLY show the data for users whose userID is found within the EventID data.

My suspicion is that either my path is wrong or I have misunderstood how Firestore is reading these rules.

EDIT: Here is the code that calls on the data

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Events")
            .orderBy("date", descending: false)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final post = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return EventCard(
                    titleEvent: post['eventTitle'],
                    locationEvent: post['eventLocation'],
                    dateEvent: post['date'],
                    timeHour: post['timeHour'],
                  timeMinute: post['timeMinute'],
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Likely answer below. If that isn't it, edit your question to show the code that isn't working against these rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I responded to your answer, same info below too: 

I've now added the code that calls on the data, an eventCard is just the card that displays the data on the screen (flutter UI card). My assumption is that I need to add a .docs(EventsID) after the .collection based on what you've said? Would this have to be the specific code of the event or is there a syntax such as EventsID that firestore would use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is hard to be certain, but my initial guess is that your code tries to read the entire `Events` collection. Keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead the rules merely check to ensure your code doesn't request more documents than it's allowed access to.

So your rules don't filter the collection to only return only documents the user owns, but rather it rejects read operations that request more documents. The solution is to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to request only documents for the current user.

In Flutter code that'd be:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("Events")
  .orderBy("date", descending: false)
  .where("userId", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid) // 
  .snapshots()
```

Comment: I've now added the code that calls on the data, an eventCard is just the card that displays the data on the screen (flutter UI card). My assumption is that I need to add a .docs(EventsID) after the .collection based on what you've said? Would this have to be the specific code of the event or is there a syntax such as EventsID that firestore would use?

Comment: You can use a query to request a list of the matching documents. See the code I added.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll have to look into this more tomorrow as it's requesting a query that is giving me trouble to set up. I appreciate the help getting me a step further.

Comment: Hi Frank, jus tto confirm this worked. The userId had to be re-written to userID but then it work perfectly. Really appreciate your help with this!